# Proper way to replace a storyboard in the Apps Hierarchy as opposed to Presenting over

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have 2 storyboards as follows:  (soon to be 3 when I add in an admin storyboard which is why I’m separating them up)

1 - Login
2 - Storyboard for Passengers

Depending if they’re logged in or not using Firebase is how I’m determining which one is presented. I’m loading using the app delegate’s didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like so to do that:

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let standbyStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StandbyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let loginStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginFlowStoryboard", bundle: nil)

    // First check if the user is logged in
    if let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
        let exampleViewController: StandbyVC = standbyStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Standby") as! StandbyVC
        self.window?.rootViewController = exampleViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    } else {
        // Not Logged In
        let exampleViewController: LoginViewController = loginStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialLogin") as! LoginViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = exampleViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

When the user logs out, I’d like to close out the Passenger storyboard and load the initial login one again (assuming they're logged in). I figured I’d do it like so, the same way I'm presenting them with the Passenger storyboard upon login:

```
func logout () {        
    let loginStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginFlowStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let exampleViewController: LoginViewController = loginStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialLogin") as! LoginViewController
    self.present(exampleViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Is this the proper way of doing it? The only reason I ask is because it appears that the deinit{} function is not getting called on the main view controller of my passenger storyboard when the log out function is called and the initial login appeared again (which led me to believe this passenger storyboard was still lingering somewhere and that I'm "stacking multiple storyboards" if that's possible and makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

> The only reason I ask is because it appears that the deinit{} function is not getting called on the main view controller of my passenger storyboard

Of course not, because instead of *replacing* the existing Passenger view controller, you are *presenting* the LoginViewController on top of it.

But please understand that that has *nothing whatever* to do with storyboards, multiple or otherwise! It's simply what `present` *means*. It all has to do with management of view controllers, and your app's view controller hierarchy. Your entire concern with storyboards, in your question title and in the question itself, is a total red herring. You could do everything you are doing with one storyboard or even with no storyboard at all, and get exactly the same result throughout.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for clearing that up, that's what I figured it was. Any guidance as to how to accomplish how to properly present the storyboard in replace of the current storyboard? I'll edit my title to make it more clear.

Comment: You don't "present a storyboard". You present a view controller. It really might help you to stop and learn about object-oriented programming (classes and instances), what a view controller is, and what a storyboard is.